# Is CAFilter still a private API?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, calayer

So I'm writing a Swift app recently and I'm creating a blur effect above imageView, I heard that CAFilter is really high efficient doing this blur job but it's a private API, according to what people had said like 3 or more years ago.
I'm wondering that whether CAFilter still banned in App Store.
Someone please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that CAFilter is being replaced by [CIFilter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIFilter_Class/) that is a class of the CoreImage Framework.

[Core Image Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185)

You can also use [UIVisualEffectView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIVisualEffectView/) to do a blur overlay, but you have less options of customization.

Comment: Thanks lorenzo! I just looked it up and implemented this to my app and it runs great now. And plus I realized from iOS 7 the blur effect provided by UIImage class is now GPU-accelerated so we don't have to worry about performance, even though it feels laggy and CPU-consuming in the Simulator, coz the Simulator doesn't have a GPU.